# I"m unable to read .csv rows recursively. Why is this showing me an error: IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, csv, gis, kml

```
def kmlForLab2(x,y):
    #XYpoints1_wgs84
    #XYpoints1_wgs84.csv
    print(x,y)
    
    #Input the file name."JoeDupes3_forearth"
    fname = input("Enter file name WITHOUT extension: ")
    data = csv.reader(open(fname + '.csv'), delimiter = ',')
    
    #Skip the 1st header row.
    #data.next()
    #Open the file to be written.
    f = open('Buffered_kml.kml', 'w')
    
    #Writing the kml file.
    f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
    f.write("<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0'>\n")
    f.write("<Document>\n")
    f.write("<!-- first buffer -->")
    f.write("<Placemark>\n")
    f.write("   <name>" + fname + '.kml' +"</name>\n")
    f.write("   <Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing>\n")
    f.write("           <coordinates>\n" )
    next(data)
    for row in data:
        #every_row = (', '.join(row))
        f.write(str(( row[x])) + "," + (str( row[y]))+ "\n") 
    f.write("           </coordinates>\n" )
    f.write("   </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon> \n")
    f.write("</Placemark>\n")
    f.write("</Document>\n")
    f.write("</kml>\n")
    f.close()
    print ("File Created. ")
    print ("Press ENTER to exit. ")

#run the function
kmlForLab2(1,2)
```

The code above works fine with this .csv file which has the header:

```
FID,X,Y
0,170.5464722,-45.75102725
1,170.5668576,-45.74410705
2,170.5830378,-45.75211941
3,170.5750982,-45.74847698
4,170.5836827,-45.75020334
5,170.5939802,-45.74689513
6,170.5857636,-45.74719562
7,170.5754473,-45.75424382
8,170.5646303,-45.7570933
9,170.5720296,-45.75808701
10,170.5690206,-45.74853323
```

but not with this file which has no header and there empty rows
in between:

```
0,-78.66408134601733,9771.5546110773,1

0,-78.65548895240566,9771.551542342384,2

0,-78.65033681160779,9771.586626160439,3

0,-78.65335636231875,9771.627622956843,4

0,-78.66177515305098,9771.63688377605,5

0,-78.66785531910878,9771.60584192237,6

0,-78.66600112895804,9771.563037346988,7

0,-78.65791969380092,9771.547876588438,8

0,-78.651044721165,9771.57425465822,9
```

The first of the .csv file was provided to me, whilst the second .csv was generated in python. I think I'm going wrong with generating the .csv file?

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively"? Please [edit] to include the full traceback. Your data samples don't look like CSV files at all.

Comment: I can't understand what is supposed to be "recursive" about this code. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]; try to find the problem yourself first, and isolate the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem. Make sure to include enough that someone else can reproduce the problem by copying and pasting without modification. For example, I have no idea what `x` and `y` values I should use to call the function.

Comment: Can you trim your code down to just the CSV-reading bit? That would make it easier for us to review, and you might find the bug while doing that.

Comment: What are the values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: You have `delimiter = ','` in the CSV reader, but there are no commas in either of the files.

Comment: Thanks. Once I opened the file in notepad, the values are separated by comma. Please check again the sample .csv file I have provided with this question.

Comment: @Barmar ... I call the function kmlForLab2(1,2) in the last line. x and y values are the row indices of the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is the delimiter

```
data = csv.reader(open(fname + '.csv'), delimiter = ',')
```

you are using `,` (comma) but it seems your file may use tabs as delimiters.

Then, you should use

```
data = csv.reader(open(fname + '.csv'), delimiter='\t')
```

#### edit

If some rows may contain not enough values, check it before accessing it

```
    for row in data:
        if len(row) > max(x,y):
            f.write(str(( row[x])) + "," + (str( row[y]))+ "\n")
```

Comment: Once I opened the file in notepad, the values are separated by comma. Please check again the sample .csv file I have provided with this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the rows that don't have enough fields.

```
cols_needed = max(x, y):
for row in data:
    if len(row) > cols_needed:
        f.write(f'{row[x]},{row[y]}\n')
```

Comment: Your suggestion did help. I went back to how I created the csv and added newline='' " ..........```with open("new_buffer.csv",'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as my_csv:
    new_buffer_csv = csv.writer(my_csv,delimiter=',')
    new_buffer_csv.writerows(df_buffer)```